# Create dynamic select element using javascript and PHP array/JSON

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code that creates an array in PHP and then uses `json_encode` for the array

```
<?php
//create array of items for nominal code box
$nominalCodes = array();
$array = Statuses('Nominal Codes');
foreach($array["results"] as $ret) {
    $nominalCodes[] = array('value' => $ret["name"], 'label' => $ret["display"].' ('.$ret["name"].')');
}
$nominalCodesData = json_encode($nominalCodes);
?>
```

i am then trying to create a select element with options from the PHP array.

I want to be able to use the data from the PHP array (value = value of select option / label = display of select option)

I have tried this code:

```
//Create array of options to be added
    var array = <?php echo $nominalCodesData; ?>;

    //Create and append select list
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "mySelect";
    Cell0.appendChild(selectList);

    //Create and append the options
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var obj = array[i];
        for(var key in obj) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = obj[key];
            option.text = key;
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
```

However, this is returning options in the select element that are:

```
label
value
label
value
label
value
label
value
label
value
label
value
label
value
label
value
label
value
```

Comment: What's the output of the php? Certainly worth editing your question to include it.

Comment: Could you maybe give us the value of `print_r($nominalCodes);` or `echo $nominalCodesData;` from your PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following JavaScript instead:

```
//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.id = "mySelect";
Cell0.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var obj = array[i];
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = obj["value"];
    option.text = obj["label"];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON indexes become properties in JavaScript, so, instead of `obj[key]` you must write `obj.key`. Next is the code (pointed by arrows ◄======):

```
<?php
//create array of items for nominal code box
$nominalCodes = array();
//$array = Statuses('Nominal Codes');
// SAMPLE DATA ▼
$nominalCodes[] = array('value' => "aaa", 'label' => "111" . ' (aaa)');
$nominalCodes[] = array('value' => "bbb", 'label' => "222" . ' (bbb)');
$nominalCodes[] = array('value' => "ccc", 'label' => "333" . ' (ccc)');
$nominalCodesData = json_encode($nominalCodes);
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="my_div">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//Create array of options to be added
    var array = <?php echo $nominalCodesData; ?>;

    //Create and append select list
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "mySelect";
    document.getElementById( "my_div" ).appendChild(selectList);

    //Create and append the options
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var obj = array[i];
      //for(var key in obj) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = obj.value;         //◄============================
            option.text = obj.label;          //◄============================
            selectList.appendChild(option);
      //}
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Copy-paste previous code in a file, save it as PHP and open it in your browser.